# Wordplay with the name Kylian (Kinglian)

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot, jeux-de-mots

Reading the title of a Greek article about the yesterday's mythical performance of Kylian Mbappé I am wondering if we can convey the following wordplay in French.

> Poland team bowed to **King**lian Mbappé.

My two cents:

> L'équipe de Pologne s'est inclinée devant le roi Mbappé.

But in this way, the wordplay is lost. Any ideas?

Comment: Did the wordplay work in Greek? What is the original title?

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Non pas du tout. Le titre grec était une combinaison grec-anglais qui permit le jeux des mots (Υποκλιθείτε στον **Κinglian** Mbappé ; i.e. bow to Kinglian Mbappé:-)!)

Comment: @Dimitris If that's how it was done in Greek, wouldn't it make sense for the French to also just say "devant Kinglian Mbappé" and assume the readers know the English word "king"?

Comment: @LukeSawczak J'ai déjà fait après avoir vu L'Équipe d'aujourd'hui et avant ton commentaire:-)! Quand même je me demande toujours si on peut faire un pun plus françisé:-)! Merci !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qui parle de roi peut peut-être parler de lion.

- L'équipe de Pologne s'est inclinée devant le lion Mbappé.

Comment: C'est une bonne idée ; merci ! Or, le jeu des mots qui existe en anglais (Kylian -> **KING**lian) est perdu en français.

Answer (score 0):

Vu la page de garde de l'Équipe d'aujourd'hui

https://www.lequipe.fr/abonnement/kiosque/le-journal/73d66ede-3818-4f6e-9edd-5f8c59d3913a

'GOD SAVE NOTRE **KING**'

je propose

> L'équipe de Pologne s'est inclinée devant le **King**lian Mbappé.

Answer (score 0):

*Kinglian* en un mot ne passe pas bien en français mais un trait d'union permet de faire ressortir *King* et de rendre compréhensible le jeu de mot :

*La Pologne s'incline devant **King-lian** Mbappé*

[image]

Source: [20 minutes](https://www.20minutes.fr/sport/psg/2322371-20180818-guingamp-psg-direct-duo-neymar-mbappe-enfin-reforme-joga-bonito-roudourou-live-16h45)